# <object> created by function called from $(document).ready not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the sample I've put together, I need to:

1. Use a jquery POST  inside $(document).ready to grab a "ticket" I use later
2. On success of the post, call another function ("AddTicketAndRender()") and pass in  that ticket
3. In AddTicketAndRender(), replace a placeholder value in an HTML template with the ticket that was passed in. The HTML template defines an object I need to render.
4. Add the HTML template to body and render:

   ```
   function addTicketAndRender(incomingTicket){

       //For now, just touch the spinner, don't worry about the ticket.
       var template = $('#tableauTemplate').html(),
           filledTemplate = template.replace('{placeholder}','yes');


       $('body').append( filledTemplate );}
   ```

I have this working in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/vm4bG/4/

However, when I combine the HTML and JavaScript together into a single htm file, the visualization I want isn't getting rendered in Chrome, IE, or Firefox.

Here is complete source from the HTM that isn't working. Can anyone see something that is obviously wrong? My markup & script is below and/or here: http://tableau.russellchristopher.org:81/rfc1.htm

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://public.tableausoftware.com/javascripts/api/viz_v1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- template code follows -->
<script type="text/template" id="tableauTemplate">

<div class="tableauPlaceholder" id="tableauPlaceholder" style="width:654px; height:1469px;background-image: url('http://tableau.russellchristopher.org:81/Background.gif'); top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; margin-left: 76px;">
    <object class="tableauViz" width="654" height="1469">
        <param name="host_url" value="http%3A%2F%2Fpublic.tableausoftware.com%2F"/>
        <param name="site_root" value="" />
        <param name="name" value="AnalyticsIncJavaScript&#47;AnalyticsInc" />
        <param name="tabs" value="no" />
        <param name="toolbar" value="yes" />
        <param name="static_image" value="tableau.russellchristopher.org:81/Background.gif"/>
        <param name="animate_transition" value="yes" />
        <param name="display_static_image" value="yes" />
        <param name="display_spinner" value="{placeholder}" id="display_spinner" />
        <param name="display_overlay" value="yes" />
        <param name="display_count" value="yes" />
    </object>
</div>
</script>
<!-- end of template -->

<body>
<script>
function addTicketAndRender(incomingTicket){

// grab tableau template code and replace ticket placeholder with incomingTicket from $.post
console.log("Add and Render");

    //For now, just touch the spinner, don't worry about the ticket.
    var template = $('#tableauTemplate').html(),
        filledTemplate = template.replace('{placeholder}','no');


    $('body').append( filledTemplate );
    console.log(incomingTicket);
    console.log("Appended.");

}

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("ready");
    var trustedURL = "http://tableau.russellchristopher.org/trusted",
        userName = "foo",
        serverURL = "http://tableau.russellchristopher.org/";


    $.post(trustedURL, {
       username: userName,
        server: serverURL,
        client_ip: "",
        target_site: ""
    }, function(response) {
        addTicketAndRender(response);
    });


});

</script>


</body>

</html>
```

Calls to console.log in the success function are logging correct information - so I know I'm getting where I need to - but the object doesn't seem to be doing what it needs to.

Comment: The Element doesn't get appended, because the DOM is not ready. That's why there is a "DOM ready" event.

Comment: Beware jsFiddle. By default, it puts your JavaScript code in the `onload` event, which happens **very, very late** in the page load process (long after "DOM ready"). And indeed your http://jsfiddle.net/vm4bG/2/ fiddle is set up exactly that way (and includes MooTools; did you want MooTools?).

Comment: But if I'm calling the function which does this work from inside $(document).ready(), wouldn't, by definition the DOM be ready?

Comment: One problem might be that you are attempting to append an element with the same `id` as an existing element. Element IDs must be unique...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FYI, your tableau.russellchristopher.org link doesn't work.  I don't know how you would have this working in jsfiddle either -- I get a cross origin error when I try it.

1. One obvious problem is that your script element that contains the template is in the nether region between `</head>` and `<body>`.  Put it inside `body`.
2. Here's what I think might be happening: it looks like the Tableau JavaScript API is setup to process the `object.tableauViz` elements when `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` fires.  You're inserting the `<object>` markup into the document in the callback for an async request.  So I'm thinking that the load events are firing, and the Tableau API is doing it's initialization before your `<object>` markup is inserted into the document.

   Perhaps register your own listeners for those events and call `console.log()` to see if they execute before your `$.post` callback.

   Unfortunately, the `createVizesAndStartLoading()` method that performs the initialization (e.g. retrieving `object.tableauViz` elements from the document) does not appear to be accessible.  It looks like you might be able to add your element by calling `window.tableau.createViz()`, but unfortunately `createVizesAndStartLoading()` does some pre-processing (e.g. setting `width` / `height` values) that you'd either need to duplicate or forego.

## Retrieve template synchronously

Try this instead of your `$.post()`:

```
$.ajax( {

  url : trustedURL,

  data : {

    username : userName,

    server : serverURL,

    client_ip : "",

    target_site : ""

  },

  async : false

} ).done( addTicketAndRender );
```

Comment: Sorry, sorry, VM hosting my webserver was down AND I managed to whack the httpd.conf with Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin...so the POST wasn't going to work till I fixed it. Which I did. FYI, tried #1, and saw no change in behavior, going to begin working on #2.

Comment: ....and now what used to work in JSFiddle no longer does. To hell with this, I'll just use PHP and .echo the ticket value in. I'm new to this stuff but managed to put a breakpoint on CreateVizesAndStartLoading(), and it's executing before the object is there. It sees 0 "parameter nodes" as a result, and those are the suckers that tell the visualization how to behave.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of suggesting using PHP or perhaps doing a synchrounous request via jQuery to pull in the template markup. If you can't include the file locally via PHP, you can probably include it via HTTP.

Comment: Can one do a synchronous request? At this point it's kind the "principal of the thing" - I'd like to see the first approach work...

Comment: Yeah, try what I show in the new section I added to my answer. I'd say just use a good tool for the job. What version of jQuery are you using? You may have to adapt the example if you're not using a recent enough version.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to tell from the vast amount of code presented exactly what you're running into, so the general principle:

In order to find and operate on a DOM element, the element must exist. So for instance, this code will fail:

```
<script>$("#target").html("Updated");</script>
<p id="target">Not updated</p>
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/equdih) | [source](http://jsbin.com/equdih/edit#html)

The target won't get updated. This code will work:

```
<p id="target">Not updated</p>
<script>$("#target").html("Updated");</script>
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/equdih/2) | [source](http://jsbin.com/equdih/2/edit)

The only difference is that the `script` tag is after the target, so you know the target exists in the DOM as of when you're trying to operate on it. (This is reliable; see [what Google's dev team have to say about it](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41), and the [YUI guidelines](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html).)

Libraries traditionally include "DOM ready" events because the built-in one, the `load` event of the `window` object, doesn't fire until *very, very late* in the process (once **all** external references have been loaded, including all images). But people wanted to do things earlier, even when images were still loading. The "ready" style events allow script code can be placed anywhere in the markup (people like putting it in `head`, for some reason), but if it uses the "ready" event, it knows that it won't actually get called until all the markup has been processed.

So the upshot is: Either use the `ready` event, or (better) move your code that relies on elements to *after* those elements in the markup (usually best right before the closing `</body>` tag).

Comment: I've been testing outside of jsbin and jsfiddler, same result. I've also moved my .ready() logic and the $.post success function right before my closing </body> tag (see above in "source that doesn't work" block) no joy. Could it be that when I append that HTML block which includes my <object> definition (after the DOM is ready) that the DOM needs to "refresh itself" and during that "refresh period" is when the rest of my code attempts to work with the <object> that has not yet been "initialized"? After a .append, is there a way to suspend the page's operation until the DOM is once more ready?

Comment: @RussellChristopher: You can manipulate DOM elements as soon as they're added. You'll have to put together a much smaller, **self-contained** example (not including scripts and stylesheets from lots of other places; and be sure to turn off the things jsFiddle turns on -- your examples are still including MooTools, as I pointed out earlier, and using the `onload` event).

Comment: @TJ Thanks again. I made at least two mistakes: re-configuring jsfiddle (MooTools / events) resolved the problem there - As you pointed out, I had things configured incorrectly. However, the markup & script which works inside jsfiddle (and what I was testing in my previous comment) still doesn't fly.